# download image from restful webservice and display in razor use asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webclient

i try to get images from a url and show the image in razor.but i can not change byte to image and show this.

```
//this is a string contains 3name of image and i give each of them with this 
   way
  string[] imgname = user.Original_images.Split(',');
        foreach (var item3 in imgname)
        {
            string url2 = "my URL" + 
             + item3 + ".jpg";

           //i download image successfully
            webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
              Convert.ToBase64String( 
              Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:password"));

            byte[] data = webclient.DownloadData(url2);

           //i don't know what should i do after this...
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my question

```
 string[] imgname = user.Original_images.Split(',');
    foreach (var item3 in imgname)
    {
        string url2 = "my URL" + 
         + item3 + ".jpg";

       //i download image successfully
        webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
          Convert.ToBase64String( 
          Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:password"));

        byte[] data = webclient.DownloadData(url2);

       //this is new
            string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteData);
            string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", 
            imageBase64Data);
            ViewBag.ImageData = imageDataURL; 
    }
```

and in razor i have this

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ImageData" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) action:

Remember you can only return one file result at a time, you can use multiple calls to controller for multiple images.

```
//changed part
return File(data , System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, item3);    

public FileResult Download()
{
    //this is a string contains 3name of image and i give each of them with this 
   way
  string[] imgname = user.Original_images.Split(',');
        foreach (var item3 in imgname)
        {
            string url2 = "my URL" + 
             + item3 + ".jpg";

           //i download image successfully
            webclient.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
              Convert.ToBase64String( 
              Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Username:password"));

            byte[] data = webclient.DownloadData(url2);

           //i don't know what should i do after this...
            return File(data , System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, item3);
        }


}
```

Comment: The code I wrote is in the middle of a method and i can't have return,and when i write this : user.img=File(data , System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, item3);[user is an object of my viewmodel and the type of img is "object" ]                     but when i want show user.img in razor i see this ContentType
application/octet-stream
FileDownloadName
!!

Comment: You can use controller to action method to retrieve the image.